# Can't use an activity as an instance of LocationListener when calling requestLocationUpdates()

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, location-services

In my App, after connecting to LocationServices.API, in the onConnected() callback, I start a location Updates Request, the problem is that the Activity that handles the process (DataActivity) is not recognize as an instance of LocationListener, it shows an error, and suggest casting.

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    PendingResult locationUpdatesResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(locationGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
}
```

When I cast the last argument to(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) the IDE lets me compile, but an ClassCastException is thrown

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.[...].DataActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

I Dont really Know why this happen.

Here is The Declaration of the Class.

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks , OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback{
```

the OnCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);

    //Create the GoogleLocationAPI reference
    buildGoogleLocationApiClient();

    //Create Location Request
    createLocationRequest();

    //Initialize the mapFragment
    initializeMapFragment();

    updateUI();
}
```

the Other Methods:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleLocationApiClient(){
    locationGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    locationGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.v("**INFO: ", "API CLIENT");
}

protected static void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    Log.i("**INFO: ", "LocationRequest created");
}

protected void initializeMapFragment(){
    //Initialize the mapFragment
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    //When mapFragment is ready...
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

**So when the connection is made (OnConnected), I call this method, when the error pops.**

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    PendingResult locationUpdatesResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(locationGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    locationUpdatesResult.await(); 
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure your `DataActivity` implements `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` and not `android.location.LocationListener`.
You may have imported `android.location.LocationListener` by mistake.

Comment: Thanks!!, that was the problem ;). I still cant vote, (reputation) but im really grateful.

Comment: Even adding com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener dint work for me...any other suggestions?

Comment: @Sharath, you may have missed the dependency "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'" on your gradle file

Comment: @Gero i imported com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener but it's not working on my fragment still crashing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks , OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback{`

do

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity implements **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**, ConnectionCallbacks , OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback{
```

after that you have to implement all its methods